# Is it possible to rotate HTML object without CSS3?

Tags: javascript, css, rotation, html2canvas

I'm building an app, where I create an canvas element of a specific div with the [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) javascript library. The problem is that it doesn't support CSS3 rotate property so if an image is rotated in the app html2canvas doesn't render it correctly (it doesnt apply rotate).

So, is it possible to rotate an HTML object without CSS3?

Answer (score 1):

you can rotate in within an other canvas element, that can be rendered in html2canvas. here is an post about that workaround:

[html2canvas and css transform rotate](http://www.jjoe64.com/2015/10/html2canvas-and-css-transform-rotate.html)

Answer (score 0):

(If you don't need to use the html2canvas library perse)

> It's is not (yet) possible to rotate objects without the use of css.
>   Some browsers (e.g. Firefox, Safari, Chrome) have there own transform
>   tag which is explained here:

http://www.zachstronaut.com/posts/2009/02/17/animate-css-transforms-firefox-webkit.html

```
.transformed {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(15deg) scale(1.25, 0.5);
    -moz-transform: rotate(15deg) scale(1.25, 0.5);
    -ms-transform: rotate(15deg) scale(1.25, 0.5);
    transform: rotate(15deg) scale(1.25, 0.5);
}
```

**Extra:**

for images you could use the jquery rotating plugin:

https://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/

for other object rotations this may be a possible solution but I don't have any experience with it:

http://coursesweb.net/javascript/rotate-html-objects-div-span-image-jquery_t

Comment: Please comment, what is wrong with the answer. Didn't I understand your question?

Comment: The OP is actually looking to rotate the element created with html2canvas library. Maybe your solution of simple jquery rotate will not work on it. That could be the reason for downvote. (BTW, I am not the one who downvoted you).

Comment: Fair enough, but if I just answer the actual question: "So, is it possible to rotate an HTML object without CSS3?" then my answer would fit his needs. If thats not what you are looking for, please comment.

Comment: I didn't downvote you Nick. My problem is not in rotating the element created with html2canvas library with CSS3 but any HTML element (div, img..). Problem starts when I rotate some element with CSS3 (transform), html2canvas ignores this property and I get the wrong canvas output.

Comment: I knew it wasn't you:) Can't my second option help you out?

Comment: Your second options uses CSS3 to create transforms.

Comment: Ok, Didn't knew that. I'm looking forward to see if I can help you somehow, but after lunch:) be right back!

Comment: I think it is just not possible at the moment to do it without CSS3 for lets say internet explorer. Some other browsers have there own transform tag which I edited in my answer.